# Reclaim an Azure DevOps organization when it is not 'orphaned'

Tags: azure-devops

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/resolve-orphaned-organization) describes the process of reclaiming an 'orphaned' Azure DevOps organization.

However, to be considered orphaned the organization must have no active administrators.

If your user is not a member of the organization, there appears to be no way to determine the members of the organization's Project Collection Administrators group (although there is [a way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/get-list-of-organizations-connected-to-azure-active-directory) to determine the organization owner).

Is there any way to reclaim an organization that is not orphaned, either because the owner is still active (but, say, unavailable) or because there are active (but unknown) users in the Project Collection Administrators group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to reclaim an organization that is not orphaned, either because the owner is still active (but, say, unavailable) or because there are active (but unknown) users in the Project Collection Administrators group.

If the organization is backed with AAD, you can still follow the doc ["Assign owner to orphaned organization"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/resolve-orphaned-organization?view=azure-devops) to claim back the organization owner when the Owner/PCA is unavailable.

You can disable sign in the owner&Project collection administrator account from Azure portal, then the `DevOps admin` user can find the `claim ownership` button when access the Organization.

Or you can submit a support ticket on azure portal or [Community forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem) to ask for support help.

Comment: Hi @jamiecon, let me know if you have any queries. If my reply answers, could you please mark it as answer? Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Hi Wade, many thanks for your answer. I did try assigning myself the role of Azure DevOps administrator but I didn't get the option to reclaim the organization when I visited the URL dev.azure.com/org-name - just an option to 'request access'. Would you expect me to see the reclaim option in that scenario?

Comment: Did you get error 401? Please access profile page: "https://aex.dev.azure.com/me?mkt=en-US", check the domain under your email, is it correct(the backed AAD)? Change it to target AAD if it's not. and try to login again. 
It's recommended to provide a screenshot in the description so that we can know the error details.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Yes the email address in that link is an AAD account. I have confirmed the organization is part of our AAD by downloading the list of organizations following the guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/get-list-of-organizations-connected-to-azure-active-directory. Screenshots: https://ibb.co/sQvtH5G, https://ibb.co/RQmPnFB. Note that in this case I did not wait an hour for AAD replication to take place after elevating in PIM but I have when trying in the past and it's the same error page.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Please go to azure portal -> AAD-> User-> click the current owner -> Profile, -> Edit to block sign in. After it's done, you should be able to see the "claim ownership" button. I confirm it works on my side.

Comment: Hi @jamiecon, i have updated the comment, could you please let me know if it's resolved? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately our company polices do not permit me to disable a user's account (even temporarily) if they are still employed by the company but unavailable. I was looking for an option to reclaim an account with an active administrator. I guess this simply isn't possible? Many thanks

Comment: In this senario, you need to submit a support ticket on [Azure Portal](https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/billing-how-to-create-billing-support-ticket.md) or [Commmunity forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem) to ask for support help. We will ask for some information and do some validation, once it's ok, we can change the owner from backend.